# Firebase app_check, play integrity does not return a valid JWT token

Tags: firebase, firebase-app-check

We are trying to validate app check token sent from an app on a custom backend.

It works on the web and on android when using the safetyNet provider. However once the playIntegrity provider is used, the token returned by firebase app check is no longer a valid JWT. It's much shorter, like this: `eyJlcnJvciI6ILVOS05QV05fRVJST1IifQ==` which seems to be HS256 encoded.

The admin node sdk api seems that it does not allow for such token as can be seen here:

https://github.com/firebase/firebase-admin-node/blob/master/src/app-check/token-verifier.ts#L115

Comment: Got the same issue - have you figure this out? @Ced

Answer (score 0):

You should go to "Play Integrity" or "Safety Net" console inside play console (depending on which provider choose). There you should register your firebase account.